# SQL - Get pairs for Employees of same city and first employee in pair takes a course taught by second

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been able to narrow this down to the appropriate pairs but I'm at a complete loss on how to filter the final part. The following  narrows it down a bit but still contains a pair that are enrolled in a class together (one of the employees is a teacher but happens to be enrolled in the class with the ohter employee thats being returned):

```
select a.ID, b.ID 
from EM as a, EM as b, ER, CR 
where a.City = b.City and a.ID <> b.ID and a.ID = ER.ID and b.ID =  
      CR.Teacher_ID and a.ID < b.ID 
group by a.ID, b.id;
```

The tables I have are:

**EM** - Employee info with fields **ID**, City, Name, Dept, salary

**ER** - Employee enrollment with fields **Cnum**, **ID**, Grade

**CR** - Course info with fields **Cnum**, Title, DEPT, Teacher_ID (matches EM.ID)

Bold fields are primary keys

The results should look like:

```
ID  |  ID
---------
E1    E2
E10   E2
```

Where both employees  are from the same city and more over, the first employee in the pair takes a course from the second employee in the pair. 
Except I end up with

```
ID  |  ID
---------
E1    E2
E10   E2
E14   E2
```

I'm getting an employee pair (E14 and E2) that are from the same city but the second employee is not teaching the first employee, they just happen to be in the same class together as students.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Can you provide some small test data and output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Simplified and dumped the derived table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    em.ID as Employee
    ,cr.Teacher_Id as Teacher
FROM
    EM em
    INNER JOIN ER er
    ON em.ID = er.ID
    INNER JOIN CR cr
    ON er.Cnum = cr.Cnum
    INNER JOIN EM te
    ON cr.Teacher_Id = te.ID
    AND em.City = te.City
```

This will get you all pairs of employees and teachers of some course that live in the same city.  DISTINCT is here in case they actually are in 2 courses together.

Note E3 and E12 are also a match as well as E4 and E13 but they are not listed in your example result.

Comment: Genius! It worked. Never would've thought to use a sub-query as a join. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this might this will solve your problem.

```
SELECT CR.Teacher_ID,ER.ID FROM EM
 INNER JOIN ER
 ON EM.ID=ER.ID
 INNER JOIN CR
 CR.CNUM=ER.CNUM
 AND CR.Teacher_ID=EM.ID
```

please reply .....

Comment: it returns an empty set

Comment: Okay what about other anwers?

Comment: i have replaced ER.Id with Em.Id try this one

Comment: Empty set as well and you forgot an "ON" at the beginning of line 5

Comment: Oh Yes I will llok into it and soon come with an answer.

Comment: this answer does not take into account the teacher and employee being in the same city.  Syntax is missing on between relationship CR & ER, and it is checking to see if a Employee ID which is in ER for a CNUM is both the student and the teacher.  0 results.

Answer (score 0):

```
select em.id,em2.id
from em join er on em.id=er.id join cr on er.cnum=cr.cnum 
join em as em2 on em2.id=cr.Teacher_ID where em.city=em2.city
```